# How to access javascript variable in php?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to access javascript variable in php, how can I can access in simple way?
consider example

```
<script "text/javascript"> 
    var a = 10; 
</script>
<?php
    echo a; // here **a** is javascript variable
?>
```

Comment: `server side` !== `client side` same as `coffee` !== `tea`

Comment: You can't, javascript run on the client and php on the server.

Comment: lmgtfy . com/?q=javascript+variable+in+php

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Answer (score 1):

You mixed both server side and client side code here. If you need to echo a javascript variable in PHP then send that variable to php file and then you can echo that variable.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to do this, pass the variable in an URL parameter and $_GET it in php;

window.location.href=index.php?var=+var+

$_GET['var']

Or, post it to your PHP file using AJAX!
Maybe you could fiddle around with JSON, but I recommend reading into AJAX;

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

I've done it a few times just by 'posting' the variables to my script

Answer (score 0):

There is two famous ways to do it: `$_GET` & `$_POST`. Both returns array of different members to the server.

$_GET is easier than $_POST.

for example, if you want to pass the variable `a` to the php script, you must make the header of your page look like `www.website.com/index.php?a=10`. So now the array of `$_GET` has `a` as a member and it's value is 10.

in your php side to call the `a` variable from the header and print it :

```
echo $_GET['a'];
```

refrence [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)